# Is this late binding or what?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, datatable, late-binding

I store encrypted email addresses in my Database and use the `DoDecrypt` Function of mine, to display the unencrypted email addresses in a AspGrid

So my LINQ query is something like

```
Dim Query = From c In DB.Something Select New With {.Email = DoDecrypt(c.Email)}
```

Which returns a set of the emails in debug mode...

After using a Linq to datatable function the results returned are the ones found in the Database, which are the encrypted ones.

What is going wrong here?
How should i modify my Linq query?

And here is the Linq to datatable function

```
 Public Shared Function ToDataTable(DB As System.Data.Linq.DataContext, query As Object) As DataTable
        If query Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("query")
        End If

        Dim cmd As IDbCommand = DB.GetCommand(TryCast(query, IQueryable))
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
        adapter.SelectCommand = DirectCast(cmd, SqlCommand)
        Dim dt As New DataTable("sd")

        Try
            cmd.Connection.Open()
            adapter.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source)
            adapter.Fill(dt)
        Finally
            cmd.Connection.Close()
        End Try
        Return dt
    End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually resolve the query, it is late bound by default, but if you're actually wanting to resolve the query, you need to just call `.ToList()`. I've just wrapped your query in brackets below and called `.ToList()` at the end. Not sure if this is the *exact* VB syntax (going from C# knowledge here), but the principal is still the same.

```
Dim Query = (From c In DB.Something Select New With {.Email = DoDecrypt(c.Email)})
.ToList()
```

Comment: Which actually throws an exception in the ToDataTable function (Value cannot be null. Parameter name: query) at line Dim cmd As IDbCommand = DB.GetCommand(TryCast(query, IQueryable))

Comment: Query will be an IEnumerable now as it's been resolved, not an IQueryable. If you change that does it work?

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1.....to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable'.

Comment: Change your TryCast to TryCast(query, IEnumerable)

Comment: I have done that but the error displayed is the one above. Should i reboot my PC? This thing freaks me up (To 'System.Linq.IQueryable'??? What the heck is going on here?)

Comment: Why don't you just change your method to take in a List? Saves you casting

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10192/discussion-between-chocol8-and-mattytommo)